# FInd position of latest smallest element in the array for all elements

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

I want to calculate, for an array of integer elements, the position of the latest element which is smaller than that element(if possible) otherwise store -1 in this place.

By latest element I mean that largest possible index smaller than current index.

Eg.

(based on 0 indexing)

let `problem[5] = {4,7,1,3,8}`

then sol `array = {-1,0,-1,2,3}`

Now I was able to do this in O(n^2) time complexity.....but am unable to do this in less than this time complexity.
So, can anyone please tell me how to do this in less than O(n^2) time complexity.

My code for n^2 time complexity :

```
int n = 5;

int ques[n] = {4, 7, 1, 3, 8};

int sol[n] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

    int pos;

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

        pos = -1;

        if (ques[j] < ques[i]) {

            pos = j;

        }

    }

    sol[i] = pos;

}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

    cout << sol[i] << ' ';

}
```

Comment: any chance you mean "[5] = {4,7,3,1,8} then sol array = {-1,0,-1,**-1**,3}" ?

Comment: Can you share with us the solution with O(n^2) and some of your attempts to solve the problem with less complexity?

Comment: I apologize !! I made the edits in the question.

Comment: And pleae don't downvote the question....I am a newbie in the programming community.

Comment: The votes are not toward you. They are for the question. They are a measure of how much we think the question is well-written, iteresting and helpful to the community. Anyway since you've edited the question I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exploit stack data structure, containing indices of elements waiting for smaller precursors. Approach is linear.

```
Make a stack `S`

Scan array `Q[]` from the end

   while (Q[i] < Q[S.top()])
        t = S.Pop()
        Sol[t] = i

   Push i onto stack

Write -1 into Sol[] for all indices remaining in the stack
```

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int ques[] = { 4, 7, 1, 3, 8 };
    int sol[] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
    stack<int> s;
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (s.size() > 0 && ques[i] < ques[s.top()]) {
            int t = s.top();
            sol[t] = i;
            s.pop();
        }
        s.push(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        cout << sol[i] << ' ';
```